# Значение из текста

Tags: c#, строки

Как можно средствами `C#` получить определенную часть строки?

У меня есть такая строка:

```
loc += "&sessionKey=16818";
```

Отсюда нужно получить само **значение** *sessionkey*, то есть только `16818`. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: регулярными выражениями

Comment: Это понятно. Но я в них вообще не силен, помоги, будь добр.

Comment: Метод `Split()` посмотрите

Comment: Это случаем не URL? Уж очень похоже на него...

Comment: @free_ze, зачем? Тут `Linq` с головой хватает

Comment: [Пожалуйста](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level4/4_10.php)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ нет, это ключ сессии в роутере.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, одно решение не исключает другое

Comment: @free_ze 403 Forbidden

Comment: @free_ze, безусловно. Но к `Regex` я стараюсь прибегать только в крайних случаях. Как никак, вещь не самая быстрая)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Собственно, как Вы уже увидели в комментариях, Ваша *проблема* имеет уйму решений!
Пройдемся по каждому)

---

### LastIndexOf

Так как нужное Вам значение находится после символа `'='`, почему бы этим не воспользоваться?

Для нахождения последнего в строке индекса, по которому находится символ `'='`, будем использовать метод [string.LastIndexOf(char)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_)

```
// Строка, откуда будем доставать значение
string parseFrom = "&sessionKey=16818";

// Возьмем подстроку из заданной строки, начиная со следующего после '=' индекса
string value = parseFrom.Substring(parseFrom.LastIndexOf('=') + 1); // 16818
```

---

### Split

Также мы можем разделить строку на массив подстрок по все тому же символу `'='`, используя метод [string.Split(params char[])](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___), тогда последней подстрокой и будет искомое значение:

```
// Строка, откуда будем доставать значение
string parseFrom = "&sessionKey=16818";

// Разделим строку по символу '=' и возьмем последнюю подстроку
string value = parseFrom.Split('=').Last(); // 16818
```

---

### Linq

По аналогии с методом **LastIndexOf** мы можем проигнорировать все символы строки до индекса, находящегося сразу после последнего в строке символа `'='`, взяв оставшуюся последовательность:

```
// Строка, откуда будем доставать значение
string parseFrom = "&sessionKey=16818";

// Пропустим все до следующего за '=' символа
string value = string.Concat(parseFrom.Skip(parseFrom.LastIndexOf('=') + 1)); // 16818
```

Или так:

```
// Строка, откуда будем доставать значение
string parseFrom = "&sessionKey=16818";

// Пропустим все до следующего за '=' символа
string value = string.Concat(parseFrom.SkipWhile(x => x != '=').Skip(1)); // 16818
```

Или же пропустим все символы, что не являются цифрой, взяв из остатка только цифры:

```
// Строка, откуда будем доставать значение
string parseFrom = "&sessionKey=16818";

// Пропустим все не цифры, взяв из остатка только цифры)
string value = string.Concat(parseFrom.SkipWhile(x => !char.IsDigit(x)).TakeWhile(x => char.IsDigit(x))); // 16818
```

---

### Regex

И только для того, чтобы пост был полным, предложу Вам решение с помощью регулярных выражений (см. [Regex](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)):

```
// Строка, откуда будем доставать значение
string parseFrom = "&sessionKey=16818";

// Достанем из строки последнее числовое значение
string value = new Regex(".*?(\\d+)").Match(parseFrom).Groups.Cast<Group>().Last().Value; // 16818
```

---

### HttpUtility.ParseQueryString

Я вижу, что Ваша подстрока ну больно напоминает часть [URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL). Так что если Ваша полная строка действительно является таковым, то, используя встроенный функционал `.NET`, мы можем спокойно получить значение параметра `URL` по его имени
Ведь, как говорится, все уже <s>украдено</s> изобретено до нас)

Воспользуемся методом [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpUtility_ParseQueryString_System_String_):

```
// Строка, откуда будем доставать значение
string parseFrom = "&sessionKey=16818";

// Полный URL
string loc = "http://127.0.0.1/?someParam=0";

// Прибавим к нему наш параметр, как в Вашем примере
loc += parseFrom;

Uri parseUri = new Uri(loc);

// Выпарсим значение параметра sessionKey
string value = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(parseUri.Query).Get("sessionKey"); // 16818
```

Или же еще проще:

Так как [Uri.Query](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.uri.query?view=netframework-4.7.2) содержит в себе все сведения запроса, мы можем только ими и оперировать! Выглядеть это будет так:

```
// Строка, откуда будем доставать значение
string parseFrom = "&sessionKey=16818";

// Выпарсим значение параметра sessionKey
string value = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(parseFrom).Get("sessionKey"); // 16818
```

---

Надеюсь, предложенные мною методы помогли Вам решить задачу, и Вы сможете дальше двигаться по пути своих свершений)
Удачи!

Comment: P.S. - почти везде в предложенных методах я добавлял взятие последнего значения из строки, так как, исходя из того, что в вопросе фигурирует некая строка `loc`, парситься, возможно, будет не только известный нам кусочек строки

Comment: Блин каждый раз захожу на этот вопрос из-за его простоты, и забываю какой шикарный тут ответ и более тут и не нужно

Comment: @SeeSharp, спасибо большое хД Я стараюсь всегда давать максимально исчерпывающие ответы по вопросам)